# How to set locale in custom action class and fetch it in another java class?

Tags: java, struts2, locale

I am a newbie to java and struts2. I need to change the locale when the user clicks on text in jsp page.I need to do this by setting the session attribute using an action class

Jsp:
    (so it would look something like this)

```
    <richtext>[url="switchLang?lang=de"]Deutsch[/url]</richtext>
```

where  "switchLang" does reset the language in the user session.

SwitchLangAction.java:

```
    public class SwitchLangAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
        Map<String, Object> session;
    @Override
        public String execute(){
            session.put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", "de");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        @Override
        public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
            this.session=session;
        }
    }
```

I need to fetch the session object in another .java file and fetch the locale. How do I do it ?

```
     class test{

    // I need to fetch the locale here 
    }
```

---

1. What should I do in switchlang.java class ??? Is my below switchLang.java correct ?
2. The footer.jsp is a part of every page in the website. I need to  reload the current page with language changes.How do I do it ?

footer.jsp:

```
    <richtext>
    [url="switchLang?request_locale=de"]Deutsch[/url]   
    [br]
    [url="switchLang?request_locale=en"]English[/url]
    </richtext>
```

switchLangAction.java:

```
    public class SwitchLangAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
        Map<String, Object> session;
    @Override
        public String execute(){
        session.put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", "de");
            return SUCCESS;
        }


        @Override
        public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
            this.session=session;
        }
    }
```

Struts.xml: // How to reload the same page ?

```
<action name="switchLang" method="execute" class="com.mobile.action.SwitchLangAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">?????</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch the session object in other java/action to class to determined user preferred locale than i believe there is other very clean and efficient way S2 provides out of the box.

Default Stack already includes an interceptor named `I18n Interceptor` which will take care of handling the user locale through the user-session.

This interceptor work around with two parameters

- parameterName (optional) - the name of the HTTP request parameter that dictates the locale to switch to and save in the session. By default this is request_locale.
- attributeName (optional) - the name of the session key to store the selected locale. By default this is WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE.

This interceptor will take care of setting the user locale in `ActionContext` each time a new request came and will set the locale as per the user request.

You have following option to ask S2 to handle I18N specific work for you

1. `<richtext>[url="switchLang?lang=de"]Deutsch[/url]</richtext>` in place of `lang=de` use the `request_locale`  as parameter key and S2 will handle the rest for you.
2. If you can not change the parameter key , create a hidden field with name `request_locale` and set the locale value before form submission.

Comment: Thank you Umesh.That was very helpful. So my modified code is :

Comment: @user1010315 you need not to put `WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE` in session.S2 interceptor is doing this for you

Comment: What should I do in switchLangAction.java class ? should I just forward it as susccess ?

Comment: How Do I reload the same page ?

Comment: @Bhavya: i m not sure what you mean by reload same page?

Comment: After the user clicks "german" , the locale has to be set to german and the page has to be reloaded in german content. How to point to reload the current page ?

Comment: What should the URL point to  in footer.jsp:  
    <richtext>
    [url=".......?request_locale=de"]Deutsch[/url]   
    [br]
    [url=".......?request_locale=en"]English[/url]
    </richtext>

Comment: @Bhavya: URL should point to your action class.Changing locale means you are picking the resources from the particular resource bundles and any other i18n specific data but i don't see any change in your action code